# Better way to exclude html elements from css

Tags: css, wordpress

I have found a really nice css code that will show links as highlighted text. Now I would like to have this style applied only on posts on my website so after adding the css style I needed to exclude other elements that will not fit into my post requirement so I ended up with this:

```css
.entry-content p a:not(.et_pb_more_button):not(.et-pb-arrow-prev):not(.et-pb-arrow-next):not(.jp-relatedposts-post-title):not(.jp-relatedposts-post-a):not(#footnote_reference_container_collapse_button){
  text-decoration:none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #bdef7a;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -4px 0 #bdef7a;
  color: inherit;
  transition: background 0.1s cubic-bezier(.33,.66,.66,1);
}

.entry-content p a:hover:not(.et_pb_more_button):not(.et-pb-arrow-prev):not(.et-pb-arrow-next):not(.jp-relatedposts-post-title):not(.jp-relatedposts-post-a):not(#footnote_reference_container_collapse_button){
  background: #bdef7a;
}
```

Besides the ugliness of the code, I still don't get the expected result inside a div containing a ul list even if it's inside the .entry-content class.

Now my question would be: What is the best approach in achieving the expected result and why does one link not show a style?

Comment: You didn't finish your question.

Comment: A) That is a _nasty_ selector. B) Just remove the `p` so it starts `.entry-content a:not(...`

Comment: Since you're using Wordpress, you can use `.single-post` to select items that are inside posts. So, Your selectors would be `.single-post .entry-content a {...}` and `.single-post .entry-content a:hover {...}`

Comment: @Ihazkode Using your solution will not apply the style on the homepage, even if that's also a post and will wrongly apply the style to the "Related" links below the post and to the "Resources" section so I will be forced to also use the :not parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the selector to apply to all links, not only those inside of a `<p>` element, change the selector from:

```
.entry-content p a:not(
```

to

```
.entry-content a:not(
```

Comment: Your solution has at least 2 downsides. On the homepage: https://cbdhempoilusa.com - the "Learn More" button on the "How Does Cannabinoids Really Work?" section has the green underline and on the initial example page the "Share this buttons" have the same underline. Tried to exclude them as I did before by adding ':not(.et_pb_button_module_wrapper et_pb_module)' but when I do that , on the homepage, I see the style disappears for good. There is something really weird going on and I think it's because the _nasty_ **:not** css parameter as

Comment: @CatherineAnderson Why can't you just give those `<a>` tags their own class? Then style that?

Comment: How can I do that for all links inside my blog posts in a wordpress CMS?

Comment: Just use the html view.

Comment: What does html view mean?

Comment: Sorry; When you are editing the WordPress page, Click the "text" tab in the content editor (upper left). Then you'll be able to easily add classes to your `<a>` elements.

Comment: This means that I will have to manually add the class to each <a> element I want this style applied to. This solution you're suggesting is worse than my ugly css code. Don't know what could be worst than that, maybe adding this style to each <a> element and not use css at all - at least that would give me additional speed

Comment: @CatherineAnderson You're right, adding the class to each <a> tag is not very scalable. Have you tried simply duplicating the big selector, and just switching out the `p` for a `ul` in the second one?